# Сортировка списка из внешнего файла С#

Tags: c#, list

Есть список объектов, у которых есть свойство `Name`. В `Name` содержатся какие то ключевые  слова, по которым я хочу сделать сортировку из внешнего файла.
Во внешнем файле находится список как раз из этих ключевых слов, ну например

```
HS
XC
TX
PD
HO
```

Сейчас, после того как задал вопрос кажется понял как это сделать))
Наверное нужно пройтись по каждому объекту и сравнить его с каждым элементом списка и записать порядковый номер например в другое свойство этого объекта.

Надеюсь, сейчас у меня получилось немного подробней расписать

Comment: я ничего не понял. Можно пример данных на входе, на выходе и ваши попытки самостоятельно решить проблему?

Comment: но если вам надо просто направление, то, я подозреваю, что вам надо отсортировать список слов по их индексам (положению) в файле.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Нужен пример списка, пример данных в файле, какой результат ожидается. Также непонятно, зачем нужен файл, можно сразу описать как выглядят загруженные ключи в какую-либо структуру. Мне например непонятно, как при множестве слов вы будете делать сортировку: каждое слово - это параметр, а как задавать направление (asc/desc) сортировкки?

Comment: Может вы имеете в виду фильтр, а не сортировку?

Comment: _Сортировка файла_ обычно подразумевает такой объём данных, который не лезет в оперативную память целиком. Сколько у вас данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Делаете из файла словарь с ключем - словом и значением - индексом в файле
2. Сортируете согласно этому индексу

Всё

```
var data = new string[] {.....};    
var sortInfo = File.ReadAllLines("your file")
        .Select((x, i) => new {Data = x, Index = i})
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Data, x=>x.Index);           
var sorted = data.OrderBy(x=>sortInfo[x]).ToArray();
```